# How to create ether wallet?

Tags: python, blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I want to create users ether wallet through code. is there any api or something to create ether wallet which they can use to transfer & receive ether ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all Ethereum network doesn't provide any API to create wallet. Any 40 digit hexadecimal string is a valid ethereum wallet with `0x` as prefix. Each wallet is created using some private key. Private key is 64 digit hexadecimal string.

Ex: `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa` is a valid private key.

And you will find address corresponding to this private key to be
`0x8fd379246834eac74B8419FfdA202CF8051F7A03`

Private keys should be very strong. So practically it is created by key derivative function.

For Node.js i use [keythereum](https://github.com/ethereumjs/keythereum)

```
function createWallet(password) {
  const params = {keyBytes: 32, ivBytes: 16};
  const dk = keythereum.create(params);

  const options = {
    kdf: 'pbkdf2',
    cipher: 'aes-128-ctr',
    kdfparams: { c: 262144, dklen: 32, prf: 'hmac-sha256' }
  };
  const keyObject = keythereum.dump(password, dk.privateKey, dk.salt, dk.iv, options);
  return keyObject;
}
 /* for getting private key from keyObject */
function getPrivateKey(password, keyObject) {
  return keythereum.recover(password, keyObject);
}

const keyObject = createWallet("My Super secret password");
const walletAddress = '0x' + keyObject.address;

const privateKey = getPrivateKey("My Super secret password", keyObject);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use pyethapp (python based client) for creating ethereum wallet, transferring funds.

Link: https://github.com/ethereum/pyethapp

It has very simple command to create account

```
$ pyethapp account new
```

Explore examples also: https://github.com/ethereum/pyethapp/tree/develop/examples

Answer (score 0):

You can use [web3py](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

```
$ pip install web3
```

Add any provider on the node you are running:

```
>>> from web3 import Web3, KeepAliveRPCProvider, IPCProvider
```

Note that you should create only one RPCProvider per process, as it recycles underlying TCP/IP network connections between your process and Ethereum node.

```
>>> web3 = Web3(KeepAliveRPCProvider(host='localhost', port='8545'))
```

Or for an IPC based connection:

```
>>> web3 = Web3(IPCProvider())
```

And voila:

```
>>> web3.personal.newAccount('the-passphrase')
['0xd3cda913deb6f67967b99d67acdfa1712c293601']
```

It created a new account.

Comment: So 0xd3cda913deb6f67967b99d67acdfa1712c293601 is the address. How can I know the private key?